# What is the significance behind so many uses of the word "murder" in old school reggae lyrics?

Tags: lyrics, reggae

Why does the word *murder* get used so much in pre-digital dancehall and old reggae?

For example, this Barrington Levy track https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmdhqRgRsmE

Is there any reason or significance?

Comment: Could it be a reference to this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_Murder_Music Or perhaps some anti war or anti violence message?

Comment: Hmm, possibly could have some influence on this but I am more thinking about late 70s / early 80s era.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Murder means "serious business". A reggae performer of that era once explained it like that in a radio interview on a London radio station back then. So not literally murder, but a colourful word for "something to be taken seriously".

But there are other possible meanings, depending on context :
See also:
https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090320003325AAvq3f9
https://www.reddit.com/r/reggae/comments/216l56/why_do_reggae_artists_use_the_phrase/